# setTimeout is not working as expected in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, css-animations

I am trying to animate six blocks, as they are `transformed` to `scale(0)` so that they are not visible at the moment. When a button is clicked `Animate` function runs and while looping it changes/updates the state

```
let [scale, setScale] = useState({prop1: 'scale(0)',
        prop2: 'scale(0)',
        prop3: 'scale(0)',
        prop4: 'scale(0)',
        prop5: 'scale(0)',
        prop6: 'scale(0)'})

const animate = () => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i ++){
        setTimeout(() => {
            let key = `prop${i}`;
            setScale(prev => ({...prev, [key]: 'scale(1)'}));
        }, 500)
    }
}
```

as the `setScale` changes the state, the UI component is updated. According to this function, what I want to do is at every loop I want to set a timeout after which the `setScale` function should execute, but that's not how it is executed. All the six blocks are rendered at once and not one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setTimeout is being executed once for each iteration of your for loop. That means that each update all executes *almost* at the same time. So after 500ms all updates happen at once.

```
const animate = () => {
    let startTime = 500;

    for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i ++){
        setTimeout(() => {
            let key = `prop${i}`;
            setScale(prev => ({...prev, [key]: 'scale(1)'}));
        }, startTime)
        startTime += 500; #increment the time so each change is half a second from the original
    }
}
```

Comment: A slightly smaller change to achieve the same result would be: `setTimeout(()=>{...}, 500 * i)`

Comment: @Micky Thank you for your explanation, now the concept is clear that why it was not working.